# Parceling a HashMap that has an array of strings

Tags: java, android, hashmap, parcelable

I have the following object:

```
public class HolderLanguageText implements Parceable { 
    final private HashMap<Integer, String[]> mapText;

    public HolderLanguagetext(Parcel in) { 
         mapText = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>();
         in.readMap(mapText, ???)

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<HolderLanguageText> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<HolderLanguageText>() {

       public HolderLanguageText createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
           return new HolderLanguageText(in);
       }

       public HolderLanguageText[] newArray(int size) {
           return new HolderLanguageText[size];
       }
    };


}
```

What do I put in the line `in.readMap(mapText, ???)`? I know it's something like `String.class.getClassLoader()`, but this is an array.

Comment: Did you tried `new String[0].getClass()`?

Comment: @Andrey - This didn't work.

Comment: Turn the HashMap into JSON. Parcel the JSON as a String.

Comment: @cricket_007 - not an option

Comment: Care to explain why? `{"value" : ["string1", "string2"]}` seems much more serializable to me than a HashMap

Comment: @cricket_007 This is legacy code that will break in many places if I do that.

Comment: How will anything break? You serialize and deserialize in the same class.

Comment: I don't mean change the HashMap to JSONObject in the `HolderLanguageText` class. Only convert the HashMap when you need to store it in the Parcel (which is simply `new JSONObject(mapText)`) , then read out the JSON in the un-parcel and store it back into the HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this in place of ????

```
Class.forName("[Ljava.lang.String;");
```

Comment: Or just try class.forName("String[]")